# Collapsed options and EE "save layout" functionality

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

The "shipping" and "Advanced" options are collapsed by default, but when I try to open them and use the "save layout" EE functionality, it doesn't "stick".

Is there an easy way around this? I'd like to keep those options open by default.

Also, id there an easy way to customize the field's names? "depth" would make a lot more sense than "Length" in my case scenario…

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think the Store "Shipping" and "Advanced" sections will be saved as open/closed when you use save layout in EE (they both default to closed).

The only way you could do this would be to edit the view files under `store/views`. Likewise if you want to change the text then you must edit the language file under `store/language`.